# Multiple Site matches (How in the world do I do this)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

So I'm making an extension that changes the CSS of the sites in a list.

I want it to work like this:

```
if url = 'https://netflix.com' {
  css = 'https://netflix.css'
}
elseif url = 'youtube.com' {
  css = 'YouTube.css'
}
```

I basically want to be able to copy and paste a new site in anytime I want to add a new site to the list.

Currently, I'm trying to do it with my manifest file.

> {
>    "manifest_version": 2,
>
> "name": "Modify CSS and HTML",
>    "version": "0.0.0",
>    "description": "Uses the CSS files to change matching websites",
>
> "content_scripts": [{
>      "css": ["yt.css"],
>      "matches": ["https://youtube.com/*"],
>      "css": ["netflix.css"],
>      "matches": ["https://netflix.com/*"]
>    }]
>
> }

But that doesn't work and I'm really new to this type of stuff. I have never done anything like this.

Any help?

Comment: content_scripts is an array with one {} object inside as you can see so simply add another {} object (after a comma) with its own matches and js/css.